# PrepareAD for Exchange Server 2013 Failed

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, exchange-2013, exchange-server

I have been trying to install Exchange Server 2013 on Windows Server 2012 Standard 64-bit, but I end up with the error:

> Active Directory must be prepared with 'Setup /PrepareAD' before
>   domains can be prepared for Exchange 2010. For more information,
>   visit:
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/library(EXCHG.150)/ms.exch.setupreadiness.DomainPrepWithoutADUpdate.aspx

I tried preparing the AD through PowerShell using the following command:

```
Setup.exe /PrepareAD /OrganizationName:"Some Name" /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms
```

but it failed for the organization preparation with the following error:

> Organization Preparation FAILED 
>   The following error was generated when
>   "$error.Clear(); initialize-ExchangeUniversalGroups -DomainController
>   $RoleDomainController -ActiveDirectorySplitPermissions
>   $RoleActiveDirectorySplitPermissions" was run: "The well-known object
>   entry B:32:C262A929D691B74A9E068728F8F842EA:CN=Organization
>   Management\0ADEL:fb018bab- f964-40ca-8438-3aa9696580cf,CN=Deleted
>   Objects,DC=hawkmain,DC=local on the otherWellKnownObjects attribute in
>   the container object CN=Microsoft
>   Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=hawkmain,DC=local points to
>   an invalid DN or a deleted object. Remove the entry, and then rerun
>   the task."

I am using the administrator account in my domain which is part of Enterprise admins and Domain admins.

Any ideas??

Comment: Didn't do any search for "Remove the entry, and then rerun the task"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue by going to AD Sites and Services and deleted the Exchange Server node + deleting the Exchange Server System OU from AD Users and Computers. I got the PrepareAD command completed successfully.

I wanted to delete everything related to exchange server. In my case, I wouldn't care about loosing anything, because its a fresh installation.

the link below helped me going through this.

ref: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/e7f62b79-c2c6-4495-bb4e-c3b46e1c4619/there-already-exists-an-organisation?forum=exchange2010

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, we need to remove "***B:32:C262A929D691B74A9E068728F8F842EA:CN=Organization Management\0ADEL:fb018bab- f964-40ca-8438-3aa9696580cf,CN=Deleted Objects,DC=hawkmain,DC=local***" from **otherWellKnownObjects** attribute.

Run "LDP.exe" on Exchange server, then try:

1. Connection  -> Connect -> Ok.
2. Connection -> Bind -> Ok.
3. View -> Tree -> CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com.
   [image]
4. Drill down to “CN=Microsoft Exhange,CN=Services…”.
5. Right Click -> Modify -> Edit Entry Attribute -> otherWellKnownObjects -> Replace -> Enter -> Run.
   [image]
   After that, re-prepare AD and install Exchange again.

Comment: I couldn't find the “CN=Microsoft Exhange,CN=Services…” directory when following your steps. But I have solved the issue by going to AD Sites and services and deleted the Exchange Server node + deleting the Exchange Server System OU from AD Users and Computers. I got the PrepareAD command completed successfully and proceeded with the setup. 

However, thank you very much for providing the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

If your exchange deployment is the first, you need the follow step:

1. prepare schema
2. prepare Active Directory
3. prepare Domain

ref: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125224(v=exchg.160).aspx

For Exchange 2013 and 2016, needed the same steps.

Comment: I did follow the steps with no use. Anyway, I got it solved by reading an answer of a different issue from technet.microsoft.com